# When auto-completing in tcsh, can I reference a previous argument?

Tags: linux, autocomplete, tcsh

I'm trying to get some efficient auto-completing going here, and have hit upon a bit of a snag.

I've got a command for setting two things at once. The first is a relatively small list, but the second, if not filtered by the first, is unmanageably huge.

What I want to be able to do is pass what's already been typed or auto-completed for the first argument to the second autocomplete command...

```
complete job 'p/1/`listJobs`/' 'p/2/`listTasks`/'
```

What I want to be able to do is pass the job that has already been entered for the first argument to the 'listTasks' command.

Any idea how I can do this?

Cheers

(this is a repost from an old SuperUser.com question of mine that nobody ever answered... The SuperUser question can be found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/208873/when-auto-completing-in-tcsh-can-i-reference-a-previous-argument))

Comment: Please add a link to the SU question, in case someone eventually answers there. And link back, for the symmetric reason.

Comment: Sure - edited on both sides...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the best option I've been able to find:

```
complete job 'p/1/`listJobs`/' \
             'p/2/`set cmd = ( $COMMAND_LINE ); listTasks $cmd[$#cmd]`/'
```

It's relying on a variable called `$COMMAND_LINE`, which is available on my Ubuntu system, but I'm not sure if it's standard.

> command  invoked from `...` version has additional environment variable set, the variable name is COMMAND_LINE and contains (as its name indicates) contents of the current (already typed
>                  in) command line. One can examine and use contents of the COMMAND_LINE variable in her custom script to build more sophisticated completions (see completion for svn(1) included  in  this
>                  package).

Failing that, you would experiment with history expansions such as `!!` or `!#$`, but I'm not sure if that will work.

Comment: Many thanks! That, I have discovered, is part of tcsh 6.17.00 (comes with Ubuntu 10.4), but not tcsh 6.14.00 (comes with Centos 5.5 and OSX)

Comment: Oh, and I would actually vote up your answer as well, but I'm unfortunately unable to, as I don't quite have the reputation for that yet...

Comment: @Hugh You're correct: tcsh-6.14.00 does not set COMMAND_LINE when calling a program within `` for autocomplete. 6.17.00 does.